# How can I create a function to replace one string column with another, based on a .startswith() conditional?

Tags: pandas, numpy, replace, conditional-statements, startswith

I have a spreadsheet where a column (`naics`*`2digit`) does not match the first two characters of the corresponding column, (`naics`*`5digit`) *which is accurate. I want to find a solution where if `naics`*`2digit` *does not match the first two characters of `naics`*`5digit`, then to replace the `naics`*`2digit` column with the first two characters of the* `naics5digit` column.

See the **bold** values below:

| industry | naics_2digit | naics_5digit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Accommodation and Food Services | 53 | 53456 |
| Real Estate | 72 | 72543 |
| Other Services | **43** | **72239** |
| Retail Trade | 81 | 81111 |
| Construction | 45 | 45789 |
| Real Estate | 23 | 23435 |
| Real Estate | **53** | **23333** |

I have tried using `np.where()` or conditional for loops with .str.startswith() or logical expressions like `naics`*`2digit != naics`*`5digit` to return rows where you could update the original table values like the following:

| industry | naics_2digit | naics_5digit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Real Estate | **53** | **23333** |

TO

| industry | naics_2digit | naics_5digit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Real Estate | 23 | 23333 |

Any suggestions?

Comment: `df['naics_2digit'] = df['naics_5digit'].astype(str).str[:2]`

Comment: Yes! I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thank you.